# Adjacent vertices of a polyhedron.

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

Given a polyhedron $P$ we have two vertices $x'$, $y'$ to be adjacent, if their convex hull is a one-dimensional face of the polyhedron. I want to show that this is equivalent to the fact, that there is a vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $x'$, $y'$ are the only two vertices of the polyhedron which maximize $c^tx$.

My line of thought for the one direction is to choose two facets $F_1,$ $F_2$ of the polyhedron who live in affine hyperplanes $H_1$, $H_2$, then choose two normal vectors $c_1$, $c_2$ on the hyperplanes and claim that $c:=\frac{1}{2} (c_1+c_2)$ does the job. I still have trouble with the details (esp. why those facets exist and why no third vertex can lie in the orthogonal complement of $c$).

For the other direction I have no clue at all which route to follow.

Comment: Yes surely, thank you! My mother tongue is not English and the German word for vertex sounds a lot like edge. :-)

Comment: Note that all of this requires a _convex_ polyhedron; else the statement doesn't need to be true.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general the average of normal vectors to the incident facets won't work (and in higher dimensions, an edge will be in more than two facets).

The definition of a face is that it is the intersection of a supporting hyperplane with $P$, yes? Take $c$ to be the normal vector to a supporting hyperplane of the one-dimensional face $[x', y']$.